# cant add any content to mysql database

Tags: php

```
 <?php

    include "config.php";

    /*
    CREATE TABLE  `addnews` (
     `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
     `auther` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
     `title` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
     `content` LONGTEXT NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
    */

    $a = $_POST['author'];
    $t = $_POST['title'];
    $c = $_POST['content'];

    if(isset($_POST["add"]) && $_POST["add"] == "news"){
        $insert = mysql_query('INSERT INTO addnews 
        (author,title,content)
        VALUES
        ("$a","$t","$c")') or die("error");
        if (isset($insert )){
            echo "<h3>Done</h3>";
        }
    };

    echo "
    <form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
    Author : <input type='text' name='author' /><br>
    Title : <input type='text' name='title' /><br>
    Content : <textarea name='content'></textarea>
    <input type='submit' value='Add news' />
    <input type='hidden' name='add' value='news' />
    </form>
    ";


    if( gettype($connectdb) == "resource") {
        mysql_close($connectdb);
    }
    ?>
```

**i am getting error from this statment i think**

```
if(isset($_POST["add"]) and $_POST["add"] == "news"){
    $insert = mysql_query('INSERT INTO addnews 
    (author,title,content)
    VALUES
    ("$a","$t","$c")') or die("error happend while trying to add information to database");
    if (isset($insert )){
        echo "<h3>Done</h3>";
    }
};
```

> **output is : error happend while trying to add information to database and no problem with config.php file (the file that connect to
>   database) i am using phpmyadmin**

http://prntscr.com/91uj3m

http://prntscr.com/91ujhe

Comment: In your config.php, you connect to mySQL, select the database, and then close the connection to mySQL immediately after that?

Comment: When relying first image is caused by an error you do not know me several hours did not appear out of a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `die("error happend while trying to add information to database");` to `die("Mysql error: " . mysql_error());` to get more information about error.

It is possible that your query fails, because you are not escaping parameters.

Modify your code to:

    `$a = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author']);
    $t = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    $c = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);`

Edit #1: Actually your problem is that you are using variables in single quoted string.
Change it to  `$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO addnews (author,title,content) VALUES ('$a','$t','$c')") or die("error: " . mysql_error());`

More information about quotes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Edit #2: If you are still learning how to work with mysql in PHP, you should learn how to use [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) instead. Mysql extension is dead (deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed from PHP 7.0)

Comment: Thanks , but I'm having another problem and you very much http://prntscr.com/91w294

Comment: now is done http://prntscr.com/91w7r7 ,, thanks thanks very very very very very much naktibalda

Answer (score 0):

Use below code as query to insert.

```
   $insert = mysql_query('INSERT INTO addnews (author,title,content) VALUES ("$a","$t","$c")');
```

Comment: Oh, and what if his variables are strings?

Comment: @Epodax I have edit my answer please check.

Comment: @sandeepsure It's just same as user4158643 did

Comment: Now done , but did not add to the database http://prntscr.com/91up0v

Comment: @user4158643 check that your variable have proper value.

Comment: @VishnuRNair According to me he has added `or` just after the mysql and that might cause error.

Comment: @sandeepsure I did not understand exactly you mean ,, but I think that everything is true ,, problem only when you type the subject does not send to the database